# Перегрузка оператора извлечения с++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Могу ли я перегрузить оператор `>>` таким образом, чтобы он сработал при следующем вызове:

```
int a = 123;
char* cstr;
a >> cstr;
```

По сути, этот оператор должен "писать" интовое значение в массив чаров(скажем, используя функцию `itoa()` внутри перегруженного оператора). Иными словами, я хочу, чтобы при вызове оператора `>>` слева стоял, например, `int`, а не поток `istream`. 
Если такая реализация возможна, то подскажите синтаксис перегрузки. Если нет, то объясните почему нельзя. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете перегружать операторы для фундаментальных типов. Для перегрузки бинарного оператора один из операндов должен быть определенный пользователем тип: либо класс, либо перечисление.

Из стандарта C++ (13.3.1.2 Operators in expressions)

> 1 If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a
>   class or an enumeration, the operator is assumed to be **a built-in
>   operator** and interpreted according to Clause 5.

Вы могли бы правый операнд "упаковать" в класс и перегрузить оператор <<, который в данном случае более естественно выглядит, следующим образом

```
class cstrClass
{
private:
    char *cstr;
    //...

public:

    friend cstrClass & operator <<( cstrClass &c, int x );
    //...
};

//...

cstrClass c;
int a, b;

//...


c << a << b;
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Подскажите, а почему оператор << в данном случае более естественно выглядит?

Comment: @Shadr Потому что, если я не ошибаюсь, вы число хотите записать в символьный массив. В данном случае символьный массив выступает как поток.